# Keeping a drag element contained inside another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, offset, containment

I'm currently working on a drag n' drop plugin. (I'm creating it because I would like other people to use it) and I want to create the `containment` feature like [jQuery draggable has it](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/constrain-movement.html).

I'm trying the following code:

```
var $div = $(o.containment);
$(oj).bind("dragstart", function (ev, dd) {
    dd.limit = $div.offset();
    dd.limit.bottom = dd.limit.top + $div.outerHeight() - $(this).outerHeight();
    dd.limit.right = dd.limit.left + $div.outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth();
}).bind('drag', function (ev, dd) {
    $(this).css({
        top: Math.min(dd.limit.bottom, Math.max(dd.limit.top, dd.offsetY)),
        left: Math.min(dd.limit.right, Math.max(dd.limit.left, dd.offsetX))
    });
});
```

About the code: `o.containment`, is just the value for the `containment` option, which in this case is: '#hi'. Which is suppose to be the containment that, `oj`, the selector for the plugin, is suppose to stay in.

Problem: `oj` (the selector) is not dragging. I hope someone can help me with this thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a working example, preferably a jsfiddle?

Comment: Im using jquery.event.drag: Not working example (I need working and that is using the version 1.5): http://jsfiddle.net/5bXT7/. And a Working example (That uses 2.0 but I can use because I need 1.5): http://jsfiddle.net/5bXT7/1/

Comment: Are you saying that the same code works when you use a different version of the drag plugin?

Comment: Yes, I thinks its because of `ev`. What is that `ev` for?